# How to use drawing for tracing in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

I don’t have scanner but I want to use hand drawing on paper in illustrator. I have laptop and iPhone I don’t know how can I make that easy so every time I span a picture of my drawing using phone. I can use it to trace in illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Take a decent quality photo of the drawing, clean it up a bit in Photoshop using levels or curves (black and white, high contrast processing) then auto-trace the result in Illustrator.

Better yet, find a friend with a scanner or pay 50 cents to have it scanned properly at a local copy shop.